# Is there a list of all RoR helpers used in view pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a list of all RoR helpers used in view pages?

Can these helpers be used in both the view pages and action pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's first distinguish `Helpers` from helpers, in the context of Rails. Helpers are helper methods available in Rails layouts and views you can use to customize the rendering of an element and/or generate HTML code.

The `Helper` is available in the [official documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/). Helpers are defined in the `ActionView::Helpers` namescope and they are grouped into modules, by their scope.

```
ActionView::Helpers
ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelFormBuilder
ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelHelper
ActionView::Helpers::ActiveModelInstanceTag
ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper
ActionView::Helpers::AtomFeedHelper
ActionView::Helpers::AtomFeedHelper::AtomBuilder
ActionView::Helpers::AtomFeedHelper::AtomFeedBuilder
ActionView::Helpers::CacheHelper
...
```

Click on a module, e.g. [ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html), to view all the helper methods defined in the module. By default, a view includes all the view helpers defined in `ActionView`, with some small exceptions (a few methods are lazy-loaded).

If you talk about controllers and actions, in the controller you can take advantage of any helper method (and with helper I mean a convenient method to access a feature) defined in the `ActionController::Base` class.

Comment: thanks, btw, in the asset helper, how does it come up with: ?1230601161

Comment: It is the asset timestamp. Rails appends it to invalidate browser/proxy caching when a new release is deployed. http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.0/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb#L781-802